# como crear el module rutas y agregar a un modulo existente por consola en angular

Tags: angular, rutas, routing

espero su ayuda

1. **ng g m rutas --routing**  :me crea el module rutas y el routing
2. pero en mi caso olvide poner --routing razón por la cual me creo solo el module rutas mas no el
   routing
3. entonces me pregunta es como crear solo este modulo routing y agregarlo al module ya creado por
   consola y con su estructura que lo crea angular como cuando haces de esta forma **ng g m rutas --routing**

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que no hay un comando para hacerlo de modo independiente, es decir el archivo routing solo es posible crearlo a la par que el módulo utilizando `--routing`. Pero podrías intentar respaldar tu avance en el componente que estás trabajando, borrarlo y crearlo de nuevo sin omitir esa línea de comando.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar el `--flat` al final del `--routing`, es decir.... quedaría así `ng g m rutas --routing --flat`

Me dices si te sirvió

Answer (score 0):

Borra el módulo rutas y lo vuelves a crear con el comando correcto, creo que es lo mas fácil y rápido.
Sobre si hay un comando que pueda crear sólamente el routing, creo que no.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no hay un comando para hacer lo que quieres, si ya tienes otros módulos con su routing.module creado, es tan sencillo como copiar el archivo correspondiente y renombrarlo.
Es decir, si tenías por ejemplo un home-routing.module.ts, lo copias a la carpeta donde no tienes módulo de enrutado y ahí lo renombras cambiando "home" por el nombre del módulo que sea.

Obviamente, dentro del nuevo archivo tienes que cambiar también las referencias al antiguo módulo por el nuevo.
Por último acuérdate de importar el nuevo routing.module en su correspondiente archivo module.ts